# Unrecognized Database Format While trying to open access 97 database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I created a mdb (Access Database 97) file with that code ,

```
  string DBPath = @"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.mdb";

        // create DB via ADOX if not exists
        if (!File.Exists(DBPath))
        {
            ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath);
            cat = null;
        }

        // connect to DB
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath);
        con.Open();
```

When I am trying to open created database it gives an "unrecognized database format" error.

I am using Microsoft Access 97 , I guess it is 32 bit.
I tried all platform targets(x86,x64 & Any CPU) from C# but still same problem.

The both access 97 and Microsoft Office 2010 installed in my computer.

The error is like that;

[image]

Could you please help me ?

Comment: I see that you're trying to connect with ACE OLEDB 12.0 driver instead of using Jet OLEDB driver. Use only Jet OLEDB driver for MS Access 97/2000.

Comment: How can I target C#project on build options? What is the name of Jet OLEDB Database Driver , I can not find it in the references?

Comment: Changed "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" to "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" and still same error while openind mdb file

Comment: It should be working for given connection string right now, try to connect with that. Check if the MDB file exist and not damaged either.

Comment: I am newly creating "mdb" file, not damaged! Not worked buddy..

Comment: Which error given by exception? Try identifying error code you've get and check it with this list: http://recoveryandmanagement.com/2014/09/05/how-to-repair-corrupted-access-database-file/

Comment: Same Error like on the above picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134736/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-bakin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After conducting deep research in hours, I found 2 main issues regarding database connection:

1. Using backslash escape sequences in a string literal doesn't converting escape sequence character, instead you should use one backslash for file path:

   ```
   string DBPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\test.mdb";
   ```
2. The connection string provider to connect with Access database in question uses Microsoft ACE OLE DB 12.0, which only supported by Access 2007 and later with ACCDB format (use [Microsoft Jet 4.0 provider](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-97/) instead).

   Additionally, in database creation part which includes `ADOX.Catalog.Create()` method, it should include `Jet OLEDB:Engine Type` parameter to specify which Access version being used. By default it sets to `Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5` which means Access 2000 file format (will trigger `unrecognized database format` error in Access 97), hence to force ADOX creating MDB with Access 97 format it is necessary to set `Engine Type=4` like below:

   ```
   // database creation
   if (!File.Exists(DBPath))
   {
       ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
       cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + DBPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=4");
       // other stuff
   }

   // connect to database using Jet OLE DB provider
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + DBPath);
   ```

Additional reference:

[Unrecognized MDB created by ADOX](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vb.database.ado/LXqIQ_KtQWM)